# how to get mouselistener notice clicks inside an imaginary triangle?

Tags: java, mouselistener, triangular

I have three  points on a grid. I want my mouselistener to give me a heads up, when a point on the area within this imaginary triangle of three points has been clicked. how to do that??I dont wanna use a shape class or anything, since it is an imaginary triangle. any ideas ? thx!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
private static final Polygon POLY = new Polygon();

static {
    POLY.addPoint(x1, y1); // first point
    POLY.addPoint(x2, y2); // second point
    POLY.addPoint(x3, y3); // third point
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
    if (POLY.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
        // notify user
    }
}
```

Note that you need to have some sort of polygon defined even though the triangle you have is "imaginary." This is so Java knows what sort of points could be inside the shape.

Comment: Yes!! works like a charm. And thx for the extra lesson about "imaginary". :-)